Plotting Low of a session AFTER a session
I would like to identify the low of the session between 00:00 and 06:00 NYT and plot it between 06:00 and 12:00 NYT. The code doesn't plot anything. I don't know what is missing or what have I done wrong so far.
//@version=5
indicator(title="Session Low", overlay=true)

// SessionLow() returns the lowest price during the given session,
// optionally corrected for the specified time zone.
// Returns 'na' when the session hasn't started or isn't on the chart.
SessionLow(sessionTime, sessionTimeZone=syminfo.timezone) =>
    insideSession = not na(time(timeframe.period, sessionTime, sessionTimeZone))
    var float sessionLowPrice = na

    if insideSession and not insideSession[1]
        sessionLowPrice := low
    else if insideSession
        sessionLowPrice := math.min(sessionLowPrice, low)
    
    sessionLowPrice

// InSession() returns 'true' when the current bar happens inside
// the specified session, corrected for the given time zone (optional).
// Returns 'false' when the bar doesn't happen in that time period,
// or when the chart's time frame is 1 day or higher. 
InSession(sessionTimes, sessionTimeZone=syminfo.timezone) =>
    not na(time(timeframe.period, sessionTimes, sessionTimeZone))

// Configure session with inputs
session  = input.session("0000-0600", title="Trading Session")
timeZone = input.string("America/New_York", title="Time Zone")

// Initialize variable to store session low
var float storedSessLow = na

// Fetch the session low
sessLow = SessionLow(session, timeZone)
storedSessLow := sessLow
// Store the session low at the end of the session
//if (time >= timestamp("America/New_York", year(timenow), month(timenow), dayofmonth(timenow), 6, 0) and time[1] < timestamp("America/New_York", year(timenow), month(timenow), dayofmonth(timenow), 6, 0))
storedSessLow := sessLow

// Define the start and end times for plotting the session low
plotStartHour = 6
plotStartMinute = 1
plotEndHour = 12
plotEndMinute = 0

plotStartTimestamp = timestamp("America/New_York", year(timenow), month(timenow), dayofmonth(timenow), plotStartHour, plotStartMinute)
plotEndTimestamp = timestamp("America/New_York", year(timenow), month(timenow), dayofmonth(timenow), plotEndHour, plotEndMinute)

// Show the stored session low on the chart between 06:01 and 12:00
plot(time >= plotStartTimestamp and time <= plotEndTimestamp ? storedSessLow : na, color=color.red, title="Session Low")
// time >= plotStartTimestamp and time <= plotEndTimestamp ? 
// To check session low visually, highlight background of session
bgcolor(InSession(session, timeZone) ? color.new(color.aqua, 90) : na)

